# Help find data sheet for micro-controller?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel

I found a packet of 10 micro-controller in my brother's electronics stuff. It reads "Atmel ATMEGA168A-PU".

I looked at Atmel's website but could not find any such product. I need it's data sheet to know that it is capable of ? I would like to play with it.

Comment: If you search on Google for `ATMEGA168A-PU` you get the datasheet as the first result. This doesn't deserve to be a question on this site.

Comment: As an aside, the letters Atmel uses as suffixes denote the microcontroller version (A) and its packaging (PU). On page 529 of the datasheet Anindo linked, you'll find *Ordering Information* which shows the various ATMEGA168's available. The "P" means it uses package 28P3. The datasheet explains this package on page 537, and it's a through-hole Plastic Dual Inline Package (PDIP). The "U" means it is lead-free. [ref](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,785.0.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here you go](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8271.pdf). Datasheet for the ATmega48A; ATmega48PA; ATmega88A; ATmega88PA; **ATmega168A**; ATmega168PA; ATmega328; ATmega328P - Atmel 8-bit Microcontroller with 4/8/16/32KBytes InSystem Programmable Flash

This microcontroller can be used to make your home-grown [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) clone, among other things. The DIP part lends itself to making the [Really Bare Bones Board](http://shop.moderndevice.com/products/rbbb-kit) quite well.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more to what Anindo Ghosh [said](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/50352/9730):

Atmel uses the following layout to their labels: **PrefixDeviceOption-Suffix** (there are no spaces so this is hard to read, with spaces it would look like: **Prefix Device Option-Suffix**)

[image]

The **AT** means it is an [Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/) part, followed by the option (this may be missing in some devices.) Then a hyphen separates the speed and package type (and sometimes temperature range and processing.)

So for the part number you gave, ATMega168A-PU:

- **AT** means Atmel
- **Mega168** is the part number
- **A** is the option, in this case smaller die and lower power usage
- **PU** is a [DIP package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package)

For more information take a look at [Explanation of Atmel’s Part Number Code](http://www.zmitac.aei.polsl.pl/Electronics_Firm_Docs/ATMEL/Atmel/acrobat/doc0538.pdf)

So as a rule of thumb, the letter before the dash (-) means:

- **P** "Picopower" low-power parts
- **A** Newer Fabrication process, lower voltage, lower power, non-Atmel fabricated parts with possibly more noise on A/D inputs
- **V** Low-voltage, lower clock frequency parts before "A" came along
- and nothing is the default part

Also, note that the **P** and **A** are not mutually exclusive, meaning that ATMega168PA-PU is a valid part number.